# How many data points is statistically significant to determine the probability of an outcome?

Tags: probability, statistics

With regards to the stock market, I currently have an 82.76% win rate over almost 500 samples. At what point is it enough to give a probability measure? Assuming that I don't change the strategy or selection criteria?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by a 'probability measure'. With a random sample of any size $n,$ you can get a 95% confidence interval that is likely to include your
true win rate. The interval gets 'tighter' (shorter) as the sample size increases.

For reasonably large $n$ the confidence interval is of the form
$$\hat p \pm 1.96 \sqrt{\frac{\hat p(1-\hat p)}{n}},$$
where $\hat p$ is the observed win rate (number of wins divided by $n).$

The assumptions for this interval are that the stock purchases are
made independently of each other and using a population and a method of selection that remain essentially the same
throughout the 500 purchases.

For the figures you quote, I get the interval $(0.7945, 0.8607),$ which has 
$\hat p = 0.8276$ as its center. It is up to you to decide whether $n = 500$ is enough purchases for this
interval to be short enough for your purposes.